# Is there a way that I can copy rows from one sheet to the other excluding existing one?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a code in Google Apps Scripts for the spreadsheet I'm currently working on. I have two sheets namely "Source" and "Destination" and the following consideration are...

1. Source have all the data and needed to be transferred to the Destination.
2. Don't copy the rows from the source sheet that are already existing in the destination sheet.
3. Only copy the rows with cells in column A that contains today's date.

Comment: What is your current issue? From `I'm trying to create a code in Google Apps Scripts for the spreadsheet I'm currently working on.`, can you provide your current script and explain the current issue?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello! welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd like to give you some advice to get the best answers here.
I think you should trim down your title: "how to copy some rows from one google sheet to another ?" Also, you are basically giving people a programming assignment. Instead, you should show that you've tried to do it yourself and describe exactly where you got stuck. Otherwise people may assume you're looking for free labour, and some of them will be rude to you.
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are have not provided any code. I think the best approach would be to look at the documentation and other answered questions here to plan your approach to solving the problem.

Since you are working at sheet to sheet level. I think a good starting point could be using range data (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet see getRange()) to read many rows of the source and compare them with the destination data. But your problem is extremely loosely defined.

That being said there are so many unanswered questions. What happens when the source and destination grow larger? I would suspect the cost of comparing the data between both the sheets would increase as well. Even if you were to process 10,000 rows of the first sheet against the contents of the destination the destination sheet would keep growing and you would have to compare each batch of the source rows against all rows of the destination.